# SAR Flood Depth Mapping

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, hec-ras

Is it possible to map flood depth using sar dataset? if yes Which sar data should be used for better result and using which software we can map?

Comment: You tag arcgis-desktop and hec-ras, but then ask about which software to use.  You have started with a very general question without providing any background.  You should add information to your question on what you have read about SAR and why you think it might be suitable (or might not)...

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to have a direct measure of flood depth with SAR images, because the signal is absorbed near the surface. However, if you  have a DEM of the area, you can measure the mean elevation of the "non water" pixels around the extent of each flooded area, and then compute the flood depth by subtraction.